# D3.js v5 making clones of selection.clones

Tags: d3.js

Hi is it possible to make a clone of a selection clone in D3 v5?

I am essentially using selection clone to make and animate circles for simulating bacteria division.
I can call d3.select.clone multiple times but that only makes duplicate clones of the first circle that I call clone on. I want to be able to make clones of the clones as well.

```
var svg = d3.select('svg')
    .style("width", '800px')
    .style("height", '600px');


  setInterval(function() {
    svg.append("circle")
            .attr("cx", 30)
            .attr("cy", 50)
            .attr("r", 15)
            .attr("id", "test_circle0")
            .style("fill", "red")

      d3.select("#test_circle0").clone(true).transition().attr("transform", "translate(25)").duration(1000);
      d3.select("#test_circle0").clone(true).transition().attr("transform", "translate(-25)").duration(3000);

  }, 1000);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to put the creation of the initial circle outside the interval. Then you can clone it inside.

To do things to the clones themselves, you can change `select` to `selectAll`

```js
var svg = d3.select('svg')
    .style("width", '800px')
    .style("height", '600px');

svg.append("circle")
            .attr("cx", 300)
            .attr("cy", 50)
            .attr("r", 15)
            .attr("class", "test-circle")

setInterval(function() {
    
    d3.select(".test-circle").clone(true).transition().attr("transform", "translate(25)").duration(1000);
    d3.selectAll(".test-circle").clone(true).transition().attr("transform", "translate(-25)").duration(3000);

  }, 1000);
```

```css
.test-circle {
    fill: red
}
```

```html
<div class="chart"></div>
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v5.min.js"  charset="utf-8"></script>
<svg></svg>
```

Comment: Is there a way to put the animation inside d3.forceSimulation so the circles don't overlap as they divide and multiply?

Comment: You could create a clustered force layout and just pop in new circles whenever, but getting the new circles to 'emerge' out of existing ones may not be doable. Honestly, your best bet is probably to use p5.js rather than d3, and just accept a little bit of math/physics simulation overhead as the cost of customizability to the specific animation you're looking for.

Comment: So is selection.clone just inherently incompatible with force layout? Or would the mechanics of force layout just make the cloning animation look wanky? I guess another alternative I could look into is a non-force layout collision detection like the one mentioned here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11339348/avoid-d3-js-circles-overlapping ?